# How to split given input json into multiple parts based on key in react for accordion?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, react-hooks, accordion

My input json is below. Based on the key values (accordionGroupOne/accordionGroupTwo) need to group arrays to create the accordion.

```
const input = [
    {
        key: "accordionGroupOne",
        type: "input",
        props: {
            label: "Input",
        }
    }, 
    {
        key: "accordionGroupOne",
        type: "dropDown",
        props: {
            label: "DropDown",
        }
    }, 
    {
        key: "accordionGroupTwo",
        type: "Input",
        props: {
            label: "Input",
        }
    }
];
```

Based on the key values (accordionGroupOne, accordionGroupTwo) need to split it into multiple parts as output below example

```
const output = [
    {
        key: "accordionGroupOne",
        title: "accordionGroupOne",
        content: [
            {
                type: "input",
                props: {
                    label: "Input",
                }
            },
            {
                type: "dropDown",
                props: {
                    label: "DropDown",
                }
            }

        ]
    }, 
    {
        key: "accordionGroupTwo",
        title: "accordionGroupTwo",
        content: [
            {
                type: "input",
                props: {
                    label: "Input",
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Javascript function to rearrange the input array.

The function will be:

```js
function groupBy(inputArray) {
  const outputArray = [];
  const keys = new Set();
  
  inputArray.forEach(item => {
    const { key, ...otherProps } = item;
    
    if (!keys.has(key)) {
      keys.add(key);
      outputArray.push({
        key,
        title: key,
        content: []
      });
    }
    
    const group = outputArray.find(group => group.key === key);
    group.content.push(otherProps);
  });
  
  return outputArray;
}
```

#### Usage:

```js
console.log(groupBy(input)) // Your input here
```